# Why is the SXA CLI tooling not open source like JSS?

Tags: sxa, sxa-cli

The Sitecore SXA CLI tooling lives in its own npm repository and does not seem to be open source like the Sitecore [JSS tooling](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss). Is there a reason why this is the case? It is not that much of a problem because the tooling in the **@sxa/cli** and the **@sxa/celt** package is readable enough in the  node_modules folder, but there is to possibility to provide pull requests.

Comment: SXA has always been closed-source. JSS is the first Sitecore offering with some degree of Open Source. Other than that, this is a decision made inside Sitecore that is unlikely to get anything but speculative answers.